# Map in react not returning multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is this returning one single option element with the contents of the array all in one line as opposed to multiple option elements??

```
<label>Model: </label>
<select>
   {this.state.unique.map(item => {
       return <option key={item}>{item}</option>;
    })}
</select>
```

Comment: what's `unique` set as an array? if so does it only have one item?

Comment: Can you show whats there in unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I was just being an idiot, when I updated the state variable I placed an array within an array.

Comment: You should mark this is the answer for your question

Comment: Apparently I have to wait two days before I can do so